# Java Client Server Socket Error: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind

Tags: java, server, client

This is the server side code
I'm pretty sure the error is that the Server Socket Isn't closing the port?
There is no problem when I run the program but, When I run it again I get this Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:550)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:539)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.bind(NioSocketImpl.java:643)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:396)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:282)
    at java.base/java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:173)
    at internet.server.main(server.java:11)
```

But if I change the port number it fixes for that one time running. Someone please help also I haven't learned java server sockets or client sockets yet soo I need help as far as I know no one else is having this problem

```
package internet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

public class server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        println("Compiled");
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5502);
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        println("Client Connected!");
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(in);
        String str = bf.readLine();
        println("Client: " + str);
        
        s.close();
        ss.close();
            
    }
    
    public static void println(String args) {
        System.out.println(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will works fine as long as you terminate your previous execution before you re run it.

Comment: I Found The Solution A Bit Ago And Totally Forgot About The StackOverFlow Page Sorry...

Answer (score -1):

Try closing those streams, InputStreamReader and BufferedReader as well. Close them before socket and ServerSocket.

```
bf.close();
in.close();
```

Comment: Doesn't Work Any Other Fixes??? (also please try to try the solution first before you say it please not trying to be rude )

Comment: Sorry if this solution doesn’t work, I see those streams weren’t closed. There may be other fixes around.

Comment: Thanks For Trying To Help Me In The First Place! If You Come Up With A Fix Please Tell Me.

Comment: *"(also please try to try the solution first before you say it please not trying to be rude )"* This answer should probably have been a comment, but if you expect people to set up a server before answering or commenting, expect less help.